# autostart audio record in Android

Tags: android, audio, record, autostart

I'm using an intent to start sound recording activity, but when the activity opens it doesn't start record. how can i autostart record? perhaps there are some extras to do it but i don't find nothing on internet and on android developers. 
here is my code

```
Intent intent=new Intent(MediaStore.Audio.Media.RECORD_SOUND_ACTION);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

i know it can be done because i found an example where it work. but i don't manage to replicate it.
Thanks in advance XD

Answer (score 1):

You're starting another application to do your audio recording.  It will start whenever that application wants it to.  If you want to start immediately, use the AudioRecord API and implement the recording yourself.

Comment: are you sure i can't do with intent? i have no time for implement Audiorecord... and in samsung "vocal function" it autostart record... XD